# Get specific text from file_get_contents

Tags: php, codeigniter, data-binding, fetch

I have a file in which i am saving message and user name now i want to get message and name separately how can i do
my code is

```
 $name  =   $this->session->userdata('name');
 $msg = isset($_GET['msg']) ? $_GET['msg'] : '';
 file_put_contents($filename,$msg.$name);
```

now i want to get data in different variables

```
$response['msg']       = file_get_contents($filename,$name);
$response['name']       =   file_get_contents($filename,$msg);
```

bt it does not featch required data...anyone knows this how to get
thanks

Comment: thanks for rep
bt on that site thy jst tell how to get value from line 24 to 29 like this bt i want to get with my own data

Comment: You're missing what file_get_contents() does.

Comment: file name has define bt not in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're sanitizing your input but anyway:

You could use some delimiter i.e:

```
file_put_contents($file, implode(';', array($msg, $name)));
```

and reading:

```
$response = explode(';', file_get_contents($filename));
```

`$response[0]` is your msg and `$response[1]` is your name.

You need to make sure that your delimiter won't be present in the message or name. You could use regular expression for that.